# HttpPostedFileBase always returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, null, httppostedfilebase

I am using MVC 4 and I tried for upload file concept.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="complianceSubDiv">
  <div class="complianceLeftDiv">
    @Html.Label("Upload the file")
  </div>
  <div class="complianceRightDiv">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
  </div>
</div>
```

My controller code like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ManageDocument(DocumentModel documentModel, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    //some code
}
```

But the `HttpPostedFileBase` file always returns null. I have searched more answers in  StackOverflow and other websites and I got the working **answer is parameter of  `HttpPostedFileBase` variable name and fileupload control name are same** . So I put the same name on all sides, but it returns `null` only.

Anyone help to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i got it

Now i replaced for `@using (Html.BeginForm())`

to

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ManageDocument", "Document", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

It's working !

Answer (score 0):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase myFile)
    {
        myFile = Request.Files["file"];
        if (myFile != null && myFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            // your code ....
        }
        return View();
    }
```

You can use "Request.Files" to get the selected file, above is the code.